# How to disable relative date display on gitweb?

Tags: git, gitweb, git-config

How can I stop gitweb from displaying all dates relative, eg: 3 days ago, 2 weeks ago, 3 days ago, 11 days ago, 21 hours ago? It gets quite annoying when I want to skim and see what changed around a certain date if they're all relative.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was hacking the source:

```
--- gitweb.cgi.orig     2015-05-05 16:19:45.341774512 +0200
+++ gitweb.cgi  2015-05-05 16:22:53.437428996 +0200
@@ -3518,13 +3518,14 @@
        $co{'age'} = $age;
        $co{'age_string'} = age_string($age);
        my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday) = gmtime($co{'committer_epoch'});
-       if ($age > 60*60*24*7*2) {
-               $co{'age_string_date'} = sprintf "%4i-%02u-%02i", 1900 + $year, $mon+1, $mday;
-               $co{'age_string_age'} = $co{'age_string'};
-       } else {
-               $co{'age_string_date'} = $co{'age_string'};
-               $co{'age_string_age'} = sprintf "%4i-%02u-%02i", 1900 + $year, $mon+1, $mday;
-       }
+# never use relative dates
+#      if ($age > 60*60*24*7*2) {
+       $co{'age_string_date'} = sprintf "%4i-%02u-%02i", 1900 + $year, $mon+1, $mday;
+       $co{'age_string_age'} = $co{'age_string'};
+#      } else {
+#              $co{'age_string_date'} = $co{'age_string'};
+#              $co{'age_string_age'} = sprintf "%4i-%02u-%02i", 1900 + $year, $mon+1, $mday;
+#      }
        return %co;
 }
```

Comment: I don't have gitweb running anymore. If anyone else wants to confirm this works, i'll mark it accepted.